# How to make sticky header and footer have arrow button to show/hide conent as Google Adsense with CSS/Boostrap and Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Please help me make sticky header and footer have arrow button to show/hide content as Google Ads with CSS/Boostrap and Jquery

**Demo Sticky Footer**
Click to down arrow button on upper left corner hide the content and show the up arrow button. When I click to up arrow button, the content of footer will show again

[image: Text]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple but working example which will help you to start. If you want to make a sticky header/footer, you have to use the following in your css:

```
 position: fixed;
```

```js
$().ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    if ($("#header").css("visibility") == "hidden")
      {
        $("#header").css("visibility", "visible").css("opacity", 1)
      }
    else  { $("#header").css("visibility", "hidden").css("opacity", 0) }
  })
})
```

```css
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #E8E8E8;
  transition:visibility 0.3s linear,opacity 0.3s linear;
  position: fixed;
}

body {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button">Show/Hide</button>
<div id="header"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. How to I change Show/Hide by Arrow Up & Down?

Comment: The easiest way is to use icon directories (bootstrap, fontawesome) through cdn or local. [Here](https://codepen.io/Szabii97/pen/qBmoGPG) is a working codepen which can help you with it! You have to refer to the bootstrap icons in the HTML head. You can find all the icons [here](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/). To show one of the icons, just use this template: **<i class='bi bi-arrow-up'></i>**. Just change the **bi-arrow-up** to your selected icon. Hope this helps!